# Puppeteer Not Triggering Click Before Returning HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, xmlhttprequest, puppeteer

My Node.js puppeteer script fills out a form successfully, but the page only accepts a "click" event on an element *some* of the time before returning the modified page content. Here's the script:

```
const fetchContracts = async (url) => {
    const browser = await pupeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const pendingXHR = new PendingXHR(page);


    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await Promise.all([
        page.click("#agree_statement"),
        page.waitForNavigation()
    ]);

    await page.click(".form-check-input");

    await Promise.all([
        page.click(".btn-primary"),
        page.waitForNavigation()
    ]);    

    /// MY PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
    /// Sometimes these clicks do not register....
    await page.click('#filedReports th:nth-child(5)')
    await pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished();
    await page.click('#filedReports th:nth-child(5)');
    await pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished();

    /// And my bot skips directly here....
    let html = await page.content();
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    return html;
```

}

The "pendingXHR" module is an import, which I pull in up top in my code from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pending-xhr-puppeteer) library:

```
const { PendingXHR } = require('pending-xhr-puppeteer');
```

The script works on my local computer, and works *some* of the time when I upload the script to Digital Ocean. According to the page that I am crawling, these clicks initiate XHR requests, which I am attempting to wait for. Here's proof:

[image]

So my question is:

Why would these clicks **not** register, even though I am awaiting them and awaiting the XHR requests, before the html is pulled from the page and then returned? And why the inconsistency with this, where *sometimes* the clicks are registered and sometimes they are not?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** The click will lead to a delayed AJAX request and therefore `pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished()` will immediately resolve as there are no requests happening at the time the function is executed. Use `page.waitForResponse('.../data/')` instead.

### Problem

You are expecting the following process of events to happen:

1. Click happens
2. AJAX request starts
3. `pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished()` executed
4. AJAX request finishes
5. Table is rendered
6. `pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished()` resolves
7. `page.content()` executed

The problem is that the library (PendingXHR) you are using [waits for the currently pending requests](https://github.com/jtassin/pending-xhr-puppeteer/blob/0b652d35b1088df6fa346e777a27c57bbbeaa9eb/src/index.js#L43) and resolves as soon as they are resolved. This does not work in two cases that I can think of:

**1. The AJAX request is started asynchronously**

In this case, the order of the events would be like this:

1. Click happens, but starts the AJAX call asynchronously (later)
2. `pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished()` executed
3. `pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished()` resolves immediately (as there are no requests)
4. `page.content()` executed **(too early!)**
5. AJAX request starts
6. AJAX request finishes
7. Table is rendered

**2. The UI modifies the table asynchronously**

In this case, the order of the events would be like this:

1. Click happens
2. AJAX request starts
3. `pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished()` executed
4. AJAX request finishes (but the code renders the table later)
5. `pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished()` resolves
6. `page.content()` **(too early!)**
7. Table is rendered

The inconsistency happens as sometimes the events might be in the right order as this is a case in which a millisecond can decide what happens first.

### Fix

Without looking at the code of the page, I cannot say which case it is for sure (it might actually be both), but I would guess it is the first one as I can totally see the table library to wait for any double clicks/dragging/etc. to happen before it makes the AJAX request.

The first problem can be fixed by using [`page.waitForResponse`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options) instead of `pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished` as this makes sure that the request to `data/` has actually happened.

Fixing the second case (if necessary) is not that trivial, but can be done by introducing a fixed waiting time by using [`page.waitFor(10)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args).

By fixing both cases, the new code looks like this:

```js
await Promise.all([ // wait for the response to happen and click
    page.waitForResponse('.../data/'), // use the actual URL here
    page.click('...'),
]);
await page.waitFor(10); // wait for any asynchronous rerenders that might happen
let html = await page.content();
```

Comment: Thank you. This was incredibly well explained, I'll no longer rely on that third-party library, now that I know this page.waitForResponse exists, and I can use it to just wait for specific resources.

Answer (score 2):

did you try to do a workaround like:

```
await page.waitfor(1000);// this line will wait for 1 Sec
```

this way you can be sure that it loaded
the better way is to put the page.click in a Promise.all Like this:

```
await Promise.all([
    await page.click('#filedReports th:nth-child(5)'),
    await pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished()
]);
```

PS: you are missing a semi-colon at

```
/// MY PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
/// Sometimes these clicks do not register....  
                                                \/
await page.click('#filedReports th:nth-child(5)')
await pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished();       /\
await page.click('#filedReports th:nth-child(5)');
await pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished();
```